# Is Text.concordance() in nltk available for pyspark as distributed method

Tags: python, apache-spark, nlp, nltk, pyspark

I'm working on Natural Language Processing using NLTK on spark. where tried to implement **3.1   Accessing Text from the Web and from Disk** part from http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html. For this I followed How to do Natural Language Processing (https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-cluster/howto/spark-nltk ). I tried to implement **text.concordance('gene')**  method but ended with result [None, None, None, None, None]. Here is my complete code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext


conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
conf.setAppName('spark-nltk')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

data = sc.textFile('/user/test/2554.txt')

def word_tokenize(x):
    import nltk
    return nltk.word_tokenize(x)

def pos_tag(x):
    import nltk
    return nltk.pos_tag([x])


words = data.flatMap(word_tokenize)
print words.take(10)


from nltk.text import Text 
text = words.map(lambda x : Text(x).concordance('gene'))
print text.take(5)



pos_word = words.map(pos_tag)
print pos_word.take(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, this:

```
text = words.map(lambda x : Text(x).concordance('gene'))
```

maps over the individual tokens in `words`.  That is, you're converting each word into a one-word text.  What you want instead of `map` is `mapPartitions`.  This

```
text = words.mapParitions(lambda x : Text(x).concordance('gene'))
```

creates one `Text` for each partition.  For example:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> data = sc.textFile(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.root + '/melville-moby_dick.txt', 10)
>>> words = data.flatMap(nltk.word_tokenize)
>>> words.map(len).take(5)
[1, 4, 4, 2, 6]
>>> words.mapPartitions(lambda t: [len(list(t))]).take(5)
[25803, 26255, 25143, 24900, 24900]
```

The first gives us the length of each word (in characters), while the second gives us the length of each partition (in words).

But, the second problem is that the `concordance` method displays the concordance lines but always returns `None`, so there's no easy way for spark to get the results.  Depending on what you want to do with the concordance, it should be easy enough to adapt `Text.concordance` to do what you want -- take a look at the source code on [github](http://github.com/nltk/nltk).

If your goal is just to be able to interactively produce concordances for really large texts, though, I'd recommend using something specially designed for that task.  For example, [IMS Corpus Workbench](http://cwb.sourceforge.net/) can perform complex searches over 100's of millions of words in seconds.

---

Comment: Great!  Could you accept the answer, so that the question won't be left open?